# Creating custom vTypes in Sencha Architect 3.0

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

How can I create custom vtypes for form fields validation in Sencha Architect 3.0. I have only found a way to include the already built in types but I want to create a custom one and include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new js based resource (or use existing one).
2. Define vtype

   ```
   Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
       myFancyValidator: function(val, field) {
           //... returns true if valid, false if not
       }
   }
   ```
3. On the  Project Inspector, browse to the field/editor that you want to validate
4. Apply vtype:'myFancyValidator'

Comment: Great answer. What are the advantages of using a vtype over the validator function?

Comment: Underneath the vtype there is probably a validator function. See this link : 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/VTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside of architect click on the + in the project inspector to bring
up the Add menu.

Select Resources-> JS Resources.

Set the URL to a location (resources/myVtypes.js)  * this is a file system location so don't include the trail slash unless you want the root directory.

Right click on the resource and select Edit Code -- this will bring up
a blank file that you can paste the class into -- and edit it within architect.

Save the project normally to update resource.

Answer (score -1):

Here sample example for create custom vtype for validate pincode numbers:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.VTypes', {

    pin: /(?!(.)\1\1).{3}/,

    init: function () {
        var me = this;

        //pin number
        this.pinFn();
        //etc..
    },
    pinFn:function () {
        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
            pin:function (val, field) {
                //check value
                return me.pin.test(val);
            },
            pinText: 'Wrong PIN number (numbers cannot be identical)'
        });
    }
});
```

After creation you can include in your form

> {
>
> fieldLabel: 'PIN Number',
>
> name: 'pin',
>
> minLength: 4,
>
> maxLength: 4,
>
> vtype: 'pin'     //coustom vtype
>
> },

Comment: How to do this in Architect? You missed that part